# Image is not moved to folder

Tags: php, mysql, image-uploading

I am trying to upload an image and move to a folder in my root directory, but nothing is happening. When I tried to make the directory from php itself, the folder wasn't created either. Now I made the folder and tried to upload but still nothing happens. I have another website which in which it creates a folder and uploads an image to it and that works fine. I tried copying the exact code from that and using it, but still nothing happens.
(I am still learning and I am running this on WAMP server on Windows)

Here is the HTML

```
<form method="post" action="?pg=editmovie&act=1" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<p class="formtext" id="topttx"> Film title </p>
<input type="text" name="title" id="topbox">

<p class="formtext" id="sttx">Director </p>
<input type="text" name="dir" id="sbox">

<p class="formtext" id="sttx">Actor 1 </p>
<input type="text" name="act1" id="actbox">

<p class="formtext" id="sttx">Actor 2 </p>
<input type="text" name="act2" id="actbox">

<p class="formtext" id="sttx">Actor 3 </p>
<input type="text" name="act3" id="actbox">

<p class="formtext" id="sttx">Genre </p>
<input type="text" name="gre" id="grbox">

<p class="formtext" id="yrtxt">Year </p>
<input type="text" name="yr" id="yrbox">

<p class="formtext" id="sttx">Film cover </p>
<input type="file" name="img">

<input type="submit" value="Add Film" name="sub">

</form>
```

and the PHP

```
function act1()
{
if(isset($_POST['sub']))
{
    $tle = $_POST['title'];
    $dir = $_POST['dir'];
    $a1 = $_POST['act1'];
    $a2 = $_POST['act2'];
    $a3 = $_POST['act3'];
    $gre = $_POST['gre'];
    $yr = $_POST['yr'];

    $conn = getDBConn();
    $sql = "INSERT INTO movies(title, director, act_1, act_2, act_3, genre, year) VALUES('$tle','$dir','$a1','$a2','$a3','$gre','$yr')";
    $output = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

    $dir = "images/films/";
    $imno = mysqli_insert_id($conn);

    $src = $_FILES['img']['tmp_name'];
    $des = $dir.$imno;
    move_uploaded_file($src,$des);
}

if($output==1)
{
    echo 'Data Stored';
}
else
{
    echo 'Data Not Stored ';
    echo mysqli_error($conn);
}
}
?>
```

**********Sorry guys, it is working properly, I have given the linked a different page in my form action so that's why it wasn't working

Comment: try to give full permission to folder

Comment: try to give image extension also

Comment: If you can't save to the folder PHP should be giving you an error. If you can give us the problem (doesn't appear to be in the code) it will be a lot easier to help you!

Comment: It is possible that there is something wrong with your upload path. Try using a absolute path to the folder.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to change code of move_upload_file() like this it's display error if any problem in image.

```
if (move_uploaded_file($src,$des);) {
    echo 'Received file' . $_FILES['file']['name'] . ' with size ' . $_FILES['file']['size'];
} else {
    echo 'Upload failed!';

    var_dump($_FILES['file']['error']);
}
```

please read this for more information [File upload Error handling](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php) and also for get specific error [specific error](http://php.net/manual/de/features.file-upload.errors.php)

Answer (score 0):

In your "php.ini" file in the wamp, search for the file_uploads directive, and set it to On:
file_uploads = On
Also set the upload folder permission to 0777.